# HTML button position

Tags: html, css

I have a html button and a css for it when I check it in firefox it seems fine but when I check in chrome the position of the button is misplaced.

The html code for the button

```
<button type='button' id='viewSubjectRating' class="button_position">View Rating</button>
```

and the css for it is

```
    .button_position
  {
    position:fixed;
    top: 575px; 
    left:950px;

  }
```

Any suggestions for this is highly appreciated.!
The image of the button are here for both the firefox and chrome:
http://postimg.org/image/opokg0z11/
http://postimg.org/image/o1fpx30b9/

Comment: Could you provide additional context?  What does the surrounding markup look like, and how is it styled?

Comment: @Annabelle is right. Can you provide some more coding.How your page design is. Post your question with complete code please.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to try `position:absolute` if you're OK with your button not being affected by any other elements. For elements, it might be better to `position` your code with `%` so the button is less likely to get squished up with other elements. This is especially useful with different screen sizes. Also try to `float` the elements the align them like a box.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the surrounding markup and style I can be certain, but it could be differences in default browser styles.  Each browser tends to have its own idea of how things should look "out of the box."

Try adding a "reset" stylesheet so that you are sure that each browser is working from the same clean slate.  For example: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/